# How to loop through array to find 4 identical values that are consecutive?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have the following swift array:

```
var winSuitArray = [cardSuit1, cardSuit2, cardSuit3, cardSuit4, cardSuit5, cardSuit6, cardSuit7]
```

`cardSuit1`, `cardSuit2` and so on, are variables that will equal strings like "clubs" or "hearts". What I want to do is loop through this array, and if the loop finds 4 identical objects whose indexes are consecutive, set the `winSuitStatus` bool to `true`.

For example, if the array looks like this:

```
["hearts", "clubs", "clubs", "clubs", "clubs", "diamonds", "spades"]
```

I want to loop through it like so:

```
for card in winSuitArray {
    //find 4 identical and consecutive objects
    // if the above requirements are met, let winSuitStatus = true
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To tell the truth, I'd probably do something similar to @KnightOfDragon's answer. There's nothing wrong with that approach. But this problem opens up some opportunities to build some much more reusable code at little cost, so it seems worth a little trouble to do that.

The basic problem is that you want to create a sliding window of a given size over the list, and then you want to know if any of the windows contain only a single value. So the first issue to to create these windows. We can do that very generally for all collections, and we can do it lazily so we don't have to compute all the windows (we might find our answer at the start of the list).

```
extension Collection {
    func slidingWindow(length: Int) -> AnyRandomAccessCollection<SubSequence> {
        guard length <= count else { return AnyRandomAccessCollection([]) }

        let windows = sequence(first: (startIndex, index(startIndex, offsetBy: length)),
                               next: { (start, end) in
                                let nextStart = self.index(after: start)
                                let nextEnd = self.index(after: end)
                                guard nextEnd <= self.endIndex else { return nil }
                                return (nextStart, nextEnd)
        })

        return AnyRandomAccessCollection(
            windows.lazy.map{ (start, end) in self[start..<end] }
        )
    }
}
```

The use of `AnyRandomAccessCollection` here is to just hide the lazy implementation detail. Otherwise we'd have to return a `LazyMapSequence<UnfoldSequence<(Index, Index), ((Index, Index)?, Bool)>, SubSequence>`, which would be kind of crazy.

Now are next question is whether all the elements in a window are equal. We can do that for any kind of Equatable sequence:

```
extension Sequence where Iterator.Element: Equatable {
    func allEqual() -> Bool {
        var g = makeIterator()
        guard let f = g.next() else { return true }
        return !contains { $0 != f }
    }
}
```

And with those two pieces, we can just ask our question. In the windows of length 4, are there any runs that area all equal?

```
let didWin = suits.slidingWindow(length: 4).contains{ $0.allEqual() }
```

---

Or we could go a little different way, and create a `SlidingWindowSequence` that we could iterate over. The logic here is basically the same. This just wraps up the windowing into a specific type rather than a `AnyRandomAccessCollection`. This may be overkill for this problem, but it demonstrates another powerful pattern.

```
public struct SlidingWindowSequence<Base: Collection>: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    let base: Base
    let windowSize: Base.IndexDistance

    private var windowStart: Base.Index

    public init(_ base: Base, windowSize: Base.IndexDistance) {
        self.base = base
        self.windowSize = windowSize
        self.windowStart = base.startIndex
    }

    public mutating func next() -> Base.SubSequence? {
        if base.distance(from: windowStart, to: base.endIndex) < windowSize {
            return nil
        }

        let window = base[windowStart..<base.index(windowStart, offsetBy: windowSize)]
        windowStart = base.index(after: windowStart)
        return window
    }
}

let didWin = SlidingWindowSequence(suits, windowSize: 4).contains{ $0.allEqual() }
```

Comment: Wow, very insightful and in depth answer. I tried your first approach, but `let didWin = winSuitArray.slidingWindowWithLength(4).contains{ $0.allEqual() }` gives me the error `Type 'String?' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'` with regards to the `allEqual` part.

Comment: My guess would be that `winSuitArray` is accidentally `[String?]` rather than `[String]`. That's exactly the message you would get in that case.

Comment: `slidingWindowWithLength()` did not return the *last* possible subsequence of the collection, so that for example  `["a", "a"].slidingWindowWithLength(2).contains{ $0.allEqual() }` evaluated to `false`. Please check my edit, I hope that it is OK.

Comment: Thanks. I was convinced I had that right, but was exactly messing up endIndex and count.

Comment: Hi is there a Swift 3 version of this it seems its not working anymore under Swift 3. thanks

Comment: Updated to Swift 3

Comment: Thanks for the update, I still see error though
**Ambiguous reference to member 'sequence()'**

Comment: @RobNapier: When using `Collection.slidingWindow(length:)` with the same length as elements in a collection, the implementation raises an exception (for example `["A", "B", "C", "D"].slidingWindow(length: 4)`).

I've changed the `guard` statement to `guard nextEnd <= self.endIndex else { return nil }` to get rid of the error.

Comment: @mkalmes Very good catch. That was an even deeper bug (it returns the wrong result for a lot of cases). It looks like I injected the problem it when converting to Swift 3. Edited as you suggested. (Also fixed the deprecation warning about IndexDistance)

Answer (score 2):

```
var suit = ""
var count = 1
for card in winSuitArray {
    if(suit == card)
    {
        count++
    }
    else
    {
      count = 1
      suit = card
    }        

    if(count == 4)
    { 
        //find 4 identical and consecutive objects
        // if the above requirements are met, let winSuitStatus = true
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, count should be 1 not 0 since you always have at least 1 card in your list you are checking

Answer (score 0):

You can use a counter variable to do this, initialized to 1.

```
for each value in array:
    if value equals previous value
        increment counter
    else
        counter = 1
    if counter >= 4
        set winCounter to true
```